# Laravel - Fetch data using Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to fetch information of the logged in user stored in the database that is to be shown on his profile page.
At the time of registration, he/she is been asked to enter the data and only a few fields are mandatory but in the 'edit profile' page he/she can add more information and then return to his profile page, where all the data should be updated. But the problem here is that only name and email is been fetched.

Controller code:

```
public function updateProfile(Request $req) {
        $name = Auth::user()->name;
        $user = Admin::where('name', $name)->first();
        if($req->input('admin-name')!= null) {
            $user->name = $req->input('admin-name');

        }

        if($req->input('admin-email')!= null) {
            $user->email = $req->input('admin-email');
        }
        if($req->input('admin-address')!= null) {
            $user->address = $req->input('admin-address');
        }
        if($req->input('admin-mobile')!= null) {
            $user->mobile = $req->input('admin-mobile');
        }
        if($req->input('admin-dob')!= null) {
            $user->dob = $req->input('admin-dob');
        }


        $user->save();


        return redirect('admin-profile')->with('update-response','Profile Updated successfully');
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                    <h4>
                    {{Auth::user()->name}}</h4>
                    <small><cite title="">{{Auth::user()->address}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                    </i></cite></small>
                    <p>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>{{Auth::user()->email}}
                        <br />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>Contact: {{Auth::user()->mobile}}
                        <br />
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>Born at {{Auth::user()->dob}}</p>    
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you `dd($req);` inside your updateProfile() function and make sure all the inputs are sent in the request?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the reference to the newly updated object of `user` to laravel instead of using the cached one, like this:

```
Auth::setUser($user);
```

Or you can work on your `Auth::user` object directly, like this:

```
...
$user = Auth::user();
$name = $user->name;
...
```

> Thanks but i have to redirect user's data to other view page

```
return redirect('admin-profile')->with([
    'update-response' => 'Profile Updated successfully', 
    'admin' => $user
]);
```

Then in your `view`:

```
<h4>{{$admin->mobile}}</h4>
```

Comment: Thanks but i have to redirect user's data to other view page

Comment: Error:Undefined variable: admin

Comment: Show us your route for `admin-profile` and code if you have any in your controller for this route

Answer (score 0):

Define an accessor in your User model.

```
class User extends Model{

    public function getMobileAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

After this you can access it:

```
{{ Auth::user()->mobile }}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')' (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/blog/resources/views/admin-profile.blade.php)

Comment: Should be `Auth::user()->mobile`.

Comment: Yup sorry :) Auth::user()->mobile